# Is it possible to write a systemd service that binds to each cpuX instance?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm trying to write a `systemd .service` unit as `myservice@.service` that automatically binds to each `cpuX` instance using `%i` when it start to create and register each instance as `myservice@cpu0.service` `myservice@cpu1.service` ... dependending on server specs.

I really don't know if it's possible to bind a service on each cpu instance, or if I need a .device or a .target unit to get the number of processors.

I have something really ugly doing it manually using a service to start each instance of `myservice@%i.service`

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExistsGlob=/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "/bin/systemctl set-environment Cpu=$(nproc --all)" 
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "for ((i=0; i<$$Cpu; i++)); do /bin/systemctl start myservice@cpu$$i.service; done"
```

Regards,

Comment: Maybe this could be solved with Systemd Generators. No experience with them though, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a udev rule which matches the CPU devices and assigns dependencies to them:

```
ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="cpu", KERNEL=="cpu*", \
    TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="myservice@%k.service"
```

The `TAG+="systemd"` will cause systemd to make a virtual `sys-whatever-cpu0.device` unit appear corresponding to each device, with the appropriate "Wants=" dependencies.

See 99-systemd.rules for similar examples. (Your custom file should also be 99-something, although in this case the order doesn't matter at all.)